# PyQt extend existing Contextual Menu when editing QstandardItem's Text (in a QtreeView)

Tags: pyqt, contextmenu, qtreeview, qstandarditem

I would like to add an action to the "default" Contextual menu that shows up when editing QStandardItem's Text (wich is shown in a QTreeView)

This contextual menu seems to be the default contextual menu of QPlainTextEdit widget. There is the default actions : Undo, Redo, Copy, Paste, Delete, Select All. I want to add a custom action just here.

I have no clue on how to modify this menu.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To customise the editor for a `QTreeView` cell you need to create a `QItemDelegate` and associate it with a column of your treeview.

Custom delegates can be more complex (eg to change the save/restore behaviour of the editor) but in this case we just want to change which class it is using to instantiate the editor widget:

```
class CustomDelegate(QItemDelegate):
    def createEditor(self, parent, option, index):
        editor = CustomLineEdit(parent)                
        return editor
```

This will ensure the editor is now a `CustomLineEdit` widget, which can have any added functionality you wish (like a custom context menu). In my example below, I use a slightly modified version of the answer provided by [Achayan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32057798/1994235) to implement this `CustomLineEdit`.

You assign a custom delegate to a column with the following code (in this case I've chosen column 0 of the treeview):

```
# Create custom Delegate which instantiates our custom editor
delegate = CustomDelegate()
# Set this delegate for the first column only
treeview.setItemDelegateForColumn(0, delegate)
```

**Full Code**

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *

class CustomLineEdit(QLineEdit):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CustomLineEdit, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.setContextMenuPolicy(Qt.CustomContextMenu)
        self.customContextMenuRequested.connect(self.__contextMenu)

    def __contextMenu(self):
        self._normalMenu = self.createStandardContextMenu()
        self._addCustomMenuItems(self._normalMenu)
        self._normalMenu.exec_(QCursor.pos())

    def _addCustomMenuItems(self, menu):
        menu.addSeparator()
        menu.addAction(u'Test', self.testFunc)

    def testFunc(self):
        print "Call"


class CustomDelegate(QItemDelegate):
    def createEditor(self, parent, option, index):
        editor = CustomLineEdit(parent)                
        return editor


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    # Create Widgets
    window = QMainWindow()
    widget = QWidget()
    layout = QVBoxLayout(widget)
    treeview = QTreeView()
    layout.addWidget(treeview)
    window.setCentralWidget(widget)
    window.show()

    # Create Model
    model = QStandardItemModel()
    model.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(['Header 1','Header 2'])
    treeview.setModel(model)

    # Create custom Delegate which instantiates our custom editor
    delegate = CustomDelegate()
    # Set this delegate for the first column only
    treeview.setItemDelegateForColumn(0, delegate)

    # Populate the model with some test data
    row1 = []
    row1.append(QStandardItem("asd"))
    row1.append(QStandardItem("fgh"))
    model.appendRow(row1)
    row2 = []
    row2.append(QStandardItem("qwe"))
    row2.append(QStandardItem("rty"))
    model.appendRow(row2)

    app.exec_()
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your precise and instructive answer @three_pineapples ! That was exactly what I was searching for. You help me a lot today :)
I just adapted your code and this is working perfectly.

Comment: @Glyphosate if this answers your question, please click the tick mark on the left hand side to mark this as the accepted answer. Once you have sufficient reputation, you will also be able up-vote any answers which you think are helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I have a example for QPlainTextEdit. You can modify based on your need. Hope this helps

```
class CustomLineEdit(QtGui.QPlainTextEdit):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(CustomLineEdit, self).__init__()
        self.setContextMenuPolicy(QtCore.Qt.CustomContextMenu)
        self.customContextMenuRequested.connect(self.__contextMenu)

    def __contextMenu(self):
        self._normalMenu = self.createStandardContextMenu()
        self._addCustomMenuItems(self._normalMenu)
        self._normalMenu.exec_(QtGui.QCursor.pos())

    def _addCustomMenuItems(self, menu):
        menu.addSeparator()
        menu.addAction(u'Test', self.testFunc)

    def testFunc(self):
        print "Call"

class mainwindow(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self , parent = None):
        super(mainwindow, self).__init__()    
        self.setupgui()
    def setupgui(self):

        self.resize(800,600)
        self.setWindowTitle('test')
        newLayout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        qlbl = CustomLineEdit()
        newLayout.addWidget(qlbl)
        self.setLayout(newLayout)
        self.show()


def main():

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = mainwindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Why someone downvoted this ? please tell me what is wrong with code if you downvote.

Comment: If I had to take a guess, it would be because this doesn't answer the question? The OP wants to do this when editing a cell in a `QTreeView`. Telling them to "adapt this code" isn't necessarily helpful.

Comment: It seems pretty straightforward to adapt the code: you just need to subclass  `QStandardItem` instead of `QPlainTextEdit`. The rest doesn't change, right ? This answer looks helpful to me.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Achayan. I am able to add custom action to a standard menu of a widget of my own. But my question is about a contextual menu of a widget that is included in the behavior of QTreeView/QStandardItem.

Comment: @tmoreau : If you subclass QstandardItem you can create/modify contextual menu when you right click. But, that is not the custom menu that shows up when you edit the name (text) of QStandardItem.